# Pls help me with this while loop nested in if condition nested in for loop 0_0

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, random, rich

I'm trying to extract a certain amount of numbers from a range of 17 numbers. However if a number is not valid (decided by the user) I need to extract another unique nuber that is different from the number not valid and the numbers that has been extracted. This is my code:

```
import random
import rich
from rich.console import Console

console = Console()
num = int(console.input('[yellow]How many number you want to extract[/yellow]: '))
non = int(console.input('[yellow]Number you want to exclude[/yellow]: '))
x = random.sample(range(1,18),num)
console.print("[yellow]Numbers extracted: [/yellow]",str(x))

for i in x:
    if i == 1:
        if non != 1:
            console.print('[green]:heavy_check_mark:[/green] Baiesi')
        else:
            console.print('❌ Baiesi')
            riserva = random.sample(range(1,18),1)
            notvalid = True
            while notvalid:
                if i not in riserva or x[i] not in riserva:
                    sosti = random.sample(range(1,18),1)
                    print(sosti)
                    notvalid = False
                else:
                    notvalid = True
                    print('unique nuber not valid')

#copy the code written before for every number until 17
```

The problem with this code is that the unique number that is supposed to be extracted is not unique: sometimes it gives numbers already extracted. Does someone have any idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your solutions is too complicated. Just create the list of numbers, remove the forbidden number from it and extract the sample:

```
num = int(console.input('[yellow]How many number you want to extract[/yellow]: '))
non = int(console.input('[yellow]Number you want to exclude[/yellow]: '))
nums = list(range(1,18)
nums.remove(non)
x = random.sample(nums, num)
for i in x:
    console.print('[green]:heavy_check_mark:[/green] Baiesi')
```